# Prove that $\int_a^bxf(x)dx\geq\frac{b+a}{2}\int_a^bf(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, integral-inequality

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous and increasing, show that
$$\int_a^bxf(x)dx\geq\frac{b+a}{2}\int_a^bf(x)dx$$
I am thinking of using integration by parts. First let
$$F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt$$
Then
$$\int_a^bxf(x)dx=bF(b)-\int_a^bF(x)dx=b\int_a^bf(x)dx-\int_a^b\int_a^xf(t)dtdx$$
So far I only have these in mind. Any one have any hints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to show that 
$$
I = \int_a^bxf(x)dx - \frac{b+a}{2}\int_a^bf(x)dx = \int_a^b \bigl(x - \frac{b+a}{2} \bigr) f(x) dx 
$$
is $\ge 0$. First split the integral in two parts:
$$ 
I =  \int_a^{(a+b)/2} \bigl(x - \frac{b+a}{2} \bigr) f(x) dx + \int_{(a+b)/2}^b \bigl(x - \frac{b+a}{2} \bigr) f(x) dx
$$
Now substitute $x = a+b-y$ in the first integral:
$$
 I = \int_{(a+b)/2}^b \bigl(\frac{b+a}{2} - y\bigr) f(a+b-y) dy + \int_{(a+b)/2}^b \bigl(x - \frac{b+a}{2}\bigr) f(x) dx \\
= \int_{(a+b)/2}^b \bigl(x - \frac{b+a}{2}\bigr) \bigl( f(x) - f(a+b - x)\bigr) dx \ge 0
$$
because $x \ge a+b-x$ in $[(a+b)/2 , b]$ and $f$ is increasing.

Comment: And, if $f$ is decreasing, the inequality goes the other way.

Answer (score 6):

Using [Chebyshev'inequality](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevIntegralInequality.html), we already have $f(x)$ and $g(x)=x$ are monotone, so $$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b xf(x) \geq \left(\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)\right)\left(\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b x\right).$$

Then one has the conclusion.

Comment: The version of Chebyshev's inequality you link to says that $f$ and $g$ should be non-negative. However, that is not necessary for Chebyshev's inequality to hold (as one can see from the proof).

Comment: Thank for your correction!

Answer (score 3):

Since $f$ is increasing, we have
$$
\frac1{b-t}\int_t^b\,f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
\ge\frac1{b-a}\int_a^b\,f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
$$
for $a\le t\le b$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_a^b(x-a)\,f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_a^b\int_a^x\,f(x)\,\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_a^b\int_t^b\,f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&\ge\int_a^b\frac{b-t}{b-a}\int_a^b\,f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac1{b-a}\int_a^b(b-t)\,\mathrm{d}t\int_a^b\,f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{b-a}2\int_a^b\,f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
$$
Adding $a\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ to both sides, we get
$$
\int_a^bx\,f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\ge\frac{b+a}2\int_a^b\,f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

Comment: can you tell me why $\int_{a}^{b}\int_{a}^{x}f(x)dtdx
 =\int_{a}^{b}\int_{t}^{b}f(x)dtdx$? Thanks

Comment: @Simple: It is just a change of order of integration. The region of integration is $\{(x,t):a\le t\le x\le b\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\int_{a}^{b} \left(x - \frac{a + b}{2}\right)dx = 0$. Since $f$ is continuous on a compact set it is bounded and it achieves minimum and since it is increasing the minimum is achieved at the lowest end of an interval and maximum at the highest end of an interval.

Let $I_{1} = \left[a, \frac{a + b}{2} \right]$ and $I_{2} = \left[\frac{a + b}{2}, b\right]$, and $g(x) = \left(x - \frac{a + b}{2} \right)$.

We have  $g(x) \leq 0, f(x) \leq f(\frac{a + b}{2})$ on $I_{1}$. So that $g(x)f(x) \geq f(\frac{a + b}{2}) g(x)$.

Similarly, $g(x) \geq 0$,  $f(x) \geq f(\frac{a + b}{2})$ on $I_{2}$. So that $g(x) f(x) \geq f(\frac{a + b}{2})g(x)$ on $I_{2}$.

Now we have:

$\int_{a}^{b}\left(x - \frac{a + b}{2} \right) f(x) dx$

$=  \int_{a}^{\frac{a + b}{2}}\left(x - \frac{a + b}{2} \right) f(x) dx  +  \int_{\frac{a + b}{2}}^{b}\left(x - \frac{a + b}{2} \right) f(x) dx$

$\geq f(\frac{a + b}{2})\left[\int_{I_{1}}g(x)dx + \int_{I_{2}} g(x) dx \right]$

$ = f(\frac{a + b}{2} )\int_{a}^{b} g(x)dx = 0$, which implies the desired inequality.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. $f(x) \ge f(a)$, but $(x-\frac{a+b}{2})$ can be *negative*, and then $\left(x - \frac{a + b}{2} \right) f(x) \le \left(x - \frac{a + b}{2} \right) f(a)$. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: I do think that you are making a point here. Will think about it but it is already almost morning. Will come back to it if no one else beat me into fixing it.

Comment: I think it is fixed now. We use $f(a)$ or $f(b)$ depending on the sign of the troublesome quantity in question:-)

Comment: $\left(x - \frac{a + b}{2} \right)f(x) \geq \left(x - \frac{a + b}{2} \right)f(a)$ holds in the first half of the interval, and $\left(x - \frac{a + b}{2} \right)f(x) \geq \left(x - \frac{a + b}{2} \right)f(b)$ holds in the second half. So you cannot "WLOG" use one of them in the entire interval $[a, b]$. – Also what makes me wonder is that the *monotony* condition is not fully used, only that the minimum is attained at the left boundary and the maximum at the right boundary.

Comment: Can we not just break up the interval then and use either of the conditions still?

Comment: Sorry to keep badgering you, but that does still not work (unless I made an error). If you evaluate the sum of the two integrals with your estimate then then result is $\frac 18 (b-a)^2 (f(a) - f(b))$, and that is negative.

Comment: It is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution for this problem. Let
$$ F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt-\frac{a+x}{2}\int_a^xf(t)dt. $$
Then
$$ F'(x)=xf(x)-\frac{1}{2}\int_a^xf(t)dt-\frac{a+x}{2}f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\int_a^x[f(x)-f(t)]dt. $$
Noting that $f(t)$ is increasing in $[a,b]$ and $a\le t\le x$, we have $f(x)\ge f(t)$ and hence $F'(x)\ge 0$ or $F(x)$ is increasing. So $F(b)\ge F(a)=0$ is the desired result.

Comment: Is there a $t$ missing in the first integral?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you're almost there. Since $f$ is increasing, we have
$$ F(x) = \int\limits_{a}^{x}{f(t)\text{ d}t} \le \int\limits_{a}^{x}{f(x)\text{ d}t} = (x-a)f(x) $$
and hence
$$\int\limits_{a}^{b}{F(x)\text{ d}x}\le\int\limits_{a}^{b}{(x-a)f(x)\text{ d}x}.$$
Hence, we have
\begin{align*}\int\limits_{a}^{b}{xf(x)\text{ d}x} = b\int\limits_{a}^{b}{f(x)\text{ d}x} - \int\limits_{a}^{b}{F(x)\text{ d}x}&\ge b\int\limits_{a}^{b}{f(x)\text{ d}x} - \int\limits_{a}^{b}{(x-a)f(x)\text{ d}x} \\
&= (b+a)\int\limits_{a}^{b}{f(x)\text{ d}x} - \int\limits_{a}^{b}{xf(x)\text{ d}x}
\end{align*}
and thus
$$ 2\int\limits_{a}^{b}{xf(x)\text{ d}x}\ge(b+a)\int\limits_{a}^{b}{f(x)\text{ d}x}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Just another way of stating it:

The inequality can be written
$$
\int_a^b f(x)\Bigl(x-\frac{a+b}{2}\Bigr)\,dx\geq 0.\tag{*}
$$
Since
$$
\int_a^b c\Bigl(x-\frac{a+b}{2}\Bigr)\,dx=0
$$
the claimed inequality $(*)$ is equivalent to
$$
\int_a^b \bigl(f(x)-c\bigr)\Bigl(x-\frac{a+b}{2}\Bigr)\,dx\geq 0,\tag{**}
$$
for any $c\in\mathbf R$. With $c=f((a+b)/2)$, the integrand in $(**)$ becomes nonnegative, and so the integral is clearly non-negative.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y = a+b - x$, notice

$$\int_a^b f(x) = \int_a^b f(y) dx\quad\text{ and }\quad\int_a^b x f(x) dx = \int_a^b yf(y) dx$$
We have
$$\begin{align}\int_a^b x f(x) dx 
&= \frac12 \int_a^b (x f(x) + y f(y) ) dx\\
&= \frac14 \int_a^b \bigg[
(\underbrace{x + y}_{= a+b})(f(x)+f(y)) + 
\underbrace{(x-y)(f(x)-f(y))}_{\ge 0  \text{ because } f \text{ is increasing }}
\bigg] dx\\
&\ge \frac{a+b}{4}\int_a^b (f(x)+f(y)) dx\\
&=   \frac{a+b}{2}\int_a^b f(x) dx
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$$
\begin{align}
0
&\color{#C00}{\le}\int_a^b\overbrace{\left(x-\frac{b+a}2\right)}^{\color{#090}{\substack{\text{integral vanishes}\\\text{over $[a,b]$}}}}\overbrace{\left(f(x)-f\left(\frac{b+a}2\right)\right)}^{\color{#C00}{\substack{\text{same sign as $x-\frac{b+a}2$}\\\text{since $f(x)$ is non-decreasing}}}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\color{#090}{=}\int_a^b\left(x-\frac{b+a}2\right)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_a^bxf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x-\frac{b+a}2\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\int_a^bxf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\ge\frac{b+a}2\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$